# docker pull gets me the error: "Download failed, retrying: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"

Tags: ssl, proxy, docker, x509certificate, x509

so I am working behind a corporate Proxy that uses it's own, self-signed certificates.

What I did was editing `~/.curlc` so that it is configured to use my proxy, as well as setting the environment variables `http_proxy` and `https_proxy`.

Then I installed the proxy's ca certificate by moving it into `\etc\ssl\certs` and creating the link to its hash via `` ln -s my_ca.pem `openssl x509 -hash -noout -in my_ca.pem`.0 ``.

So now I can `curl` and `wget` and everything works fine.

Next I created the directory `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d` and created a new file in it called `http-proxy.conf`:

```
[Service]
Environment= "HTTP_PROXY=http://user:pass@proxy.corp.net:3128/" "HTTPS_PROXY=https://user:pass@proxy.corp.net:3128/"
```

After doing that `docker search` works as it should but I still cannot pull a container from the official registry.

`systemctl status docker` tells me: `Download failed, retrying: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`

So I really don't know what else I can do for it to work. Maybe anybody on here has an idea?

## EDIT

The full output of a `docker pull` call when running the docker daemon in debug mode:

```
DEBU[0092] Calling GET /v1.22/info
DEBU[0092] GET /v1.22/info
DEBU[0092] Calling POST /v1.22/images/create
DEBU[0092] POST /v1.22/images/create?fromImage=httpd%3Alatest
DEBU[0092] Trying to pull httpd from https://registry-1.docker.io v2
DEBU[0093] Increasing token expiration to: 0 seconds
DEBU[0094] Pulling ref from V2 registry: httpd:latest
DEBU[0094] pulling blob "sha256:7268d8f794c449e593d3a48f62e7e22b7c3a4b6e615caaf9494ec3cb2d48f503"
DEBU[0094] pulling blob "sha256:a3ed95caeb02ffe68cdd9fd84406680ae93d633cb16422d00e8a7c22955b46d4"
DEBU[0094] pulling blob "sha256:5d77cae53716e669a240114fc676b26cb052cb325078c869f884cab8a658be17"
ERRO[0095] Download failed, retrying: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
ERRO[0095] Download failed, retrying: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
ERRO[0095] Download failed, retrying: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
...
```

Comment: Hey, I got a bad news! Your company spies on you and remove/add its own home-made certificate so you cannot browse the Internet securely. A tsocks could be a solution (but you need an outside ssh server), another solution, insecure, would be to add the bad certificate to your trusted certificate. (just like if you would remove your car airbag and tell yourself it's safe).

Comment: Ok, how would you go on adding the bad certificate to the trusted. Didn't I alread do that?

Comment: I think that this [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/90607/157077) is what you are looking for. Tell me if it works, then I'll post it as an answer ;)